# JSON.parse(request.responseText) won't return all data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

This is the javascript portion that is in question. I'm using JSON.parse and when I log it in the console, the description key/value is not showing up.

```
var jsonOptions = JSON.parse(request2.responseText);
jsonGlobal = jsonOptions; 
console.log(request2.responseText);
```

my json file looks like this

```
[{"level": "1","number": "1","title": "blah blah blah","description": "aaaa"},
{"level": "1","number": "1.1","title": "blah again","description": "aaa" }]
```

This is the full javascript

```
<script>
var dataList2 = document.getElementById('json-datalist');
var input2 = document.getElementById('ajax2');
var request2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
var jsonGlobal ;

request2.onreadystatechange = function (response) {

    if (request2.readyState === 4) {
        if (request2.status === 200) {
            // Parse the JSON
            var jsonOptions = JSON.parse(request2.responseText);
            jsonGlobal = jsonOptions; 
            console.log(request2.responseText);
            // console.log(jsonGlobal)
            // Loop over the JSON array.
            jsonOptions.forEach(function (item) {
                // Create a new <option> element.
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                // Set the value using the item in the JSON array.
                option.value = item.title;
                option.setAttribute('data-number', item.number);
                option.setAttribute('data-description',item.description); // add this line for description
                //<--
                // Add the <option> element to the <datalist>.
                dataList2.appendChild(option);
            });

            // Update the placeholder text.
            input2.placeholder = "Start Enterting a Title...";
        } else {
            // An error occured :(
            input2.placeholder = "Couldn't load datalist options :(";
        }
    }
};


// Update the placeholder text.
input2.placeholder = "Loading options...";

// Set up and make the request2.
request2.open('GET', '/static/json/all-titles.json', true);
request2.send();
</script>
```

This is what shows up in the console

```
[
 {
  "level": "1",
  "number": "1",
  "title": "blah blah blah"
 },
```

Any thoughts on why the description section is not showing up?

Comment: Does your script work? Do you get any errors, such as from `JSON.parse`? Or is it just the `console.log` that's bugging you?

Comment: `JSON.parse` would throw an error on partial JSON. What does the network panel say, does the server send all expected values? I could imagine the console cutting off strings that are too long.

Comment: the script doesn't throw any errors but JSON.parse does not completely read in all of the JSON which doesn't allow me to use that value and pass it into an update function. I ran my JSON through jsonlint.com to validate and it approves it as well

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains the answer:

When you do `console.log(request2.responseText)` you say you receive the following output:

```
[
 {
  "level": "1",
  "number": "1",
  "title": "blah blah blah"
 },
```

This line has nothing to do with JSON parsing. It's simply printing out what the response contains. Your server is not sending the description data in the response.